# How to generate oauth token?

Tags: oauth

The OAuth 1.0 Protocol didn't point out the algorithm servers generating tokens. What algorithm should I use? Is random sequence OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secret part of each set of credentials (client, temporary, token) should be as random and as long as reasonably possible. You want to prevent anyone from discovering the secrets by intercepting a request and cracking the signature.

The section [Entropy of Secrets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-4.9) in the OAuth 1.0a spec goes into more detail (but not much more).

I usually read from `/dev/urandom` (on Linux systems) to get a binary string of 12 or 15 random bytes and then base64 encode it. You might make the client secret longer since it changes rarely if ever.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't implemented a server myself, but random ought to work. Something similar to what you'd use for nonce() in a client.